# functions don't work in files with html doctype

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>  
<div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="510" height="510"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        draw();

        function (ctx) {
            cxt.moveTo(10, 10);
            cxt.lineTo(500, 10);
            cxt.stroke();
        }
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this doesn't work, however, if I delete the function draw() and put the codes in script, it works, like the  following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
    cxt.moveTo(10,10);
    cxt.lineTo(500,10);
    cxt.stroke();
</script>
```

I want to know how can I make the funciton works

Comment: Why do you include the jquery library and then never use it?

Comment: You have no closing `</script>` tag, and your function syntax is invalid..

Comment: I would say this yields an 'draw is not defined'-error? And indeed, draw is not defined, so everything after draw(); won't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

The two code snippets are not equivalent. The first example defines (and immediately discards) an anonymous function. That function is never called, which is why it looks like your code "does not work."

Fix the indentation and this becomes fairly obvious:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
draw();

// Syntax error here
function(ctx){
    cxt.moveTo(10,10);
    cxt.lineTo(500,10);
    cxt.stroke();
}
```

As commenters have already pointed out, the first example is also missing a `</script>` closing tag. I don't know what you're trying to do differently from the second example, which should work just fine for you, but I assure you – the problem has *nothing* to do with the doctype.

Comment: The first one does not define and discard an anonymous function. If the script was to be evaluated, it would never get off the ground because the function would be a syntax error.,

Comment: Yes, the interpreter will attempt to parse it as a function declaration, and will throw when it sees that there's no name, as required. Make it an expression, and it'll succeed *(at least through the parsing phase)*.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should learn how to set & invoke functions, first.

This sets a function:

```
function draw(ctx) {
    // etc
}
```

And this invokes it, with `ctx` as the argument:

```
draw(ctx);
```

Don't forget to pass argument. There are two variables named `ctx` in your code, but their scopes are different. Don't just assume that your function should know which value it should take as `ctx` inside the function.